# Why doesn't the node object have the field name?

Tags: entities, theming

When I use the following code in page--front.tpl.php, it doesn't show the name of the field label, why? What code should I use to print the field label?

```
$node = node_load(1);
print_r($node);
```

The output is similar to the following:

```
    [field_sq] => Array(
      [zh-hans] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
          [value] => 250
        )
      )
    )
```